# Crystal for Visual Studio upgrade not updating web.config or references

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, web-config

I have VS2010 and VS2012 installed together with CR for VS 13.0.2.  All good, I have the same application I'm opening on both vs2010 and vs2012 (busy with migration from 2010 to 2012).

I have updated CR for VS from 13.0.2 to 13.0.6.  The problem I'm facing, is that my files in the crystal folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet) have all been upgraded from 13.0.2 to 13.0.6 which I can see if I right click, properties, details each file.

I open vs2010/2012 and in there, the web.config file isn't being updated and if I look at the properties of the references for CR it's all still showing 13.0.2.  Also, if I look up the file references (by right clicking references, add reference), I can see that those exact files which are now 13.0.6, are still being listed as 13.0.2.

Previously, whenever I moved from one VS to the next (2005 -> 2008 -> 2010) and upgraded the crystal, it would upgrade the files automatically except for way back in 2005 days where a lot of it had to be fixed by hand, so I'm thinking this might be something to that effect.

I've tried uninstalling CR for VS completely and reinstalling it, but it's not doing anything.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I "think" I might have resolved what it is that's happening.  Posting my answers in case it helps someone else.

I've been going at this as much as possible over the last few days and I keep coming up with the same conclusion.  I've also updated my test server now to see what that does and that also does the same.

Once I run the CR for VS or the Runtime depending on if the pc is a dev pc or a hosting server, it shows the files on the file system are overwritten with new files and the assemblies stills shows the actual versions as 13.0.2000.0 and I think the 2000 is not the same as the version 13.0.2.x vs 13.0.6.x so I am going to leave things as is for now just with the latest 13.0.6.x runtime because even in the IDE's, it shows the version as 13.0.2000.0 but the file version as 13.0.6.1027 so I'm sure that's right.

If anyone else has any info regarding this, please feel free to offer a better explanation than I can come up with, but the reports are all running and everything "seems" fine for now.